# The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

```
public List<User> Getdata()
{
     using (var context =new  huntableEntities())
     {             
         IQueryable<User> userrecords = (context.Users.Where(x => x.RecuiteReferalId == 24));
         userrecords.ToList().ForEach(u =>
                                         {

                                          u.CurrentCompany =
                                                 u.EmploymentHistories.Where(
                                                         e => e.IsCurrent && e.MasterCompany != null).Select(
                                                             e => e.MasterCompany.Description).FirstOrDefault();
                                                 u.CurrentPosition =
                                                     u.EmploymentHistories.Where(
                                                         e => e.IsCurrent && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.JobTitle)).
                                                         Select(e => e.JobTitle).FirstOrDefault();
                                         });
        return userrecords.AsEnumerable().ToList();
     }          
}
```

I am getting the `object context disposed` at the return statement

I tried by making the query and method `IEnumerable` but the result was the same. 
I also tried by setting the lazy loading false.

Any guess where I am going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried changing `userrecords.ToList().ForEach` to `userrecords.AsEnumerable().ToList().ForEach`

Answer (score 0):

After you call `ToList` you are executing the query and as such disconnecting the entities from the context - You need to remove the call to `ToList` *before* your call to `ForEach` i.e.

```
userrecords.ForEach(u => ...);
```

Also, there is no need to call `AsEnumerable` as your return type is`List<User>`, just call `ToList` before you return the query i.e.

```
return userrecords.ToList();
```

Not only should this solve your problem, but it is more efficient as your now only hitting the database once.

Comment: userrecords.ForEach will not work out check once in the solution userrecords does not have foreach

Comment: @manojchowdary you could write an [extension method](http://mfelicio.com/2010/01/13/c-tips-ienumerablet-foreach-extension-method/) for it, or just use good ol' `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing the extension method, you should just use a regular Foreach loop to get the benefits of what @James is saying. Plus, you could also clean up your LINQ queries:

```
foreach (var u in userrecords)
{
  u.CurrentCompany = u.EmploymentHistories
                      .FirstOrDefault(e => e.IsCurrent && e.MasterCompany != null)
                      .MasterCompany.Description;

  u.CurrentPosition = u.EmploymentHistories
                       .FirstOrDefault(e => e.IsCurrent && string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.JobTitle))
                       .JobTitle;
}
```

And just have it return `userrecords.ToList()`.

One more thing to note, though: If at any point you try to use of the navigational properties on the `User` records, you may also get the same exception, since the connection will have already closed, and it's trying to lazy load the entities without having a connection (and thus fails). In such a case you can either turn off lazy loading or you can just, in this method, actually make a call to that property (not to change anything, just to read it) to have it load before the connection is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the context would be disposed when you `return` the list, but there is a sneaky twist in your code that would yield unexpected results anyway. Your `ForEach` statement does not change anything! `userrecords` is an `IQueryable` and the only thing you do is enumerate it twice: in the `ForEach` and in the `ToList()` in the `return` statement.

You can prevent this by creating a list at the start:

```
List<User> userrecords = context.Users
                        .Include("EmploymentHistories.MasterCompany")
                        .Where(x => x.RecuiteReferalId == 24)
                        .ToList();
userrecords.ForEach(u => ...
```

The `Include` is to prevent n + 1 queries. A disposed context should not be an issue now.

Comment: It would be disposed if you try to access any of the navigational properties outside of this method and if lazy loading is enabled. When you do that it tries to go back to the database to actualize the entities, only to see that it's been disposed.

Comment: @IronMan84 Of course, but why "at the return statement" as the OP states? The ToList() is carried out within the scope of the context.